# Scroll page after clicking an arrow

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to scrolling up a page from down to up after clicking on arrow.

```js
var $arrow = $("#arrow a");
$("#arrow").on("click", function() {
  $("body,html").animate({
    scrollTOP: 400
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria- hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- na Youtubie jest + aria-hidden="true"-->
</header>
<main></main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Shows me errors:

> '$' was used before it was defined.   var $arrow = $("#arrow a");
>   Missing 'use strict' statement.   $("body,html").animate({
>   Expected ';' and instead saw '}'. }, 1000)
>   Expected ';' and instead saw '(end)'. })

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary spaces in the path to jQuery on the CDN. That's causing the error with the `$` variable. Remove those spaces.

Comment: that spaces appears only here when I copy to this post, in index.html there are no spaces at all.

Comment: Sorry for that.  But it does not work - doesnt scrolling. I do not know why:/

Answer (score 1):

**Try Following Without Animate**

```
$("#arrow").on("click", function() {
 $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + " px");
})
```

Comment: Bendy Zhang fixed problem, I wrote scrollTOP instead scrollTop. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $arrow = $("#arrow a");
$("#arrow").on("click", function() {
  $("body,html").animate({
    scrollTop: 400
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="arrow">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true">Go</i>
  </div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p><p>1</p>
  <!-- na Youtubie jest + aria-hidden="true"-->
  <p>2</p>
</header>
<main>
</main>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Above code worked. 
Note that use `scrollTop` instead of `scrollTOP`

Comment: OMG! It was so frustrated. You helped a lot. Thank you. It is working!

Comment: Voted: close as simple typo: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.